# Prevent ability to perform reverse nameserver lookup on server for domain names

Tags: dns, reverse

is there any possible way to prevent Joe Public from accessing the entire catalog of domain names on my web server, using a reverse nameserver lookup? Other than ghosting my nameservers. I use branded nameservers, so it's quite easy to reverse them, but is there a way I can stop this revealing how many and exactly which domains are hosted on those nameservers?

Comment: Question is good for a sister site of SO. Check [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Enjoy SO.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, DNS data is public.  Anyone can build reverse and forward mapping databases which are independent of the public DNS (but use data from it).  For example, Microsoft built such a reverse lookup service into its Bing search engine:

- [Bing reverse lookup for 151.101.1.69](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ip:151.101.1.69)

At the time of writing, 151.101.1.69 was one of the IP addresses used by StackOverflow, and the search results reflect that.

In the Bing case, their DNS database probably was built from the activities of their web crawlers.  Other databases use various [zone file transfer programs](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/program-status/czds) as a starting point to look for domain names.  Others use [passive DNS replication](http://www.enyo.de/fw/software/dnslogger/).

There is no way to avoid this level of scrutiny once a service is offer to the public over the Internet.